# formatting and display of complex text that is not supposed to be mathematical

Tags: formatting, text-manipulation

I have been messing around with these two sections for awhile now and I cannot seem to get them to compile correctly.  Both are complex in terms of the symbols used and the fact that I believe Latex is trying to go into math mode, but I am not sure.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, twoside]{article}
\usepackage{baskervald}
\usepackage[margin=1in,bindingoffset=15.5mm,heightrounded]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[notes]{biblatex-chicago}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{setspace}
\newcommand*{\textsubscript}[1]{$#1{}$}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{references = {Works Cited}}
\DeclareBibliographyCategory{primary}
\makeindex
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}

\begin{document}
    \begin{quote}
    \noindent 
    \textbf{110} in-parts{]} ~\textsubscript{^}~ || 
    \textbf{112} long-smother'd{]} long \textsubscript{^}smothered ||  
    \textbf{118} SD \emph{Exit Mons}.{]} \emph{placed as in Dilke; after l. 117} | 
       \emph{with Pages}.{]} \emph{Boas subs}. | \emph{Manet Buss}.{]} 
       \emph{after l. 119 }||  
    \textbf{119} SD Rising.{]} (See Textual Note) ||  
    \textbf{122-126} Like \ldots soyl{]} \emph{stet} (\emph{See Textual Note}) ||  
    \textbf{127} nourish any{]} norishany ||  
    \textbf{130} for{]} \emph{stet} (\emph{See Textual Note}) | vertue,] ~; ||
    \end{quote}

    \begin{quote}
    \noindent To be, or not to be, \{that is the q/Question\}/\{I there's the point,\} 
    \ldots 
    t/To \{d/Die/dye /,  --/ to sleepe, --/\}/\{die to sleepe,\} \{ \}/{is that all? I all:\}
    \{ \}/ \{No,\} t/To sleepe ,/! {perchance}/\{ \} to d/Dreame ,/;/!  I/ay /, \{there's the rub,/;\}/\{mary there it goes,\}
    \ldots
    \{The faire Ophelia ,/?/:/! --/ Nimph/Nymph /,\}/\{Lady,\} in thy o/Orizons/orisons \{, be all my sinnes remembred\}/
    \{Be all my sinnes remembred/remember'd.\}  /?
        \end{quote}
\end{document
```

For the first I tried escaping the square brackets in curly brackets **{]}** and for the second I escaped the curly brackets { } but besides those, I have not added anything to the text as I would like it to be portrayed.  I am trying to avoid the verbatim environment as I would like to display this like the rest of the text.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: `\textsuperscript{^}` will surely raise an error. And also the lonely `&`. This is not a compilable example, so it's impossible to help without guessing.

Comment: Sorry, I keep forgetting about the MWE!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really should reconsider how you are doing things an define macros for things you want to do often so that the input is more readable.  But to fix your curent prooblem, I defined `\textsubscript` as I am not sure where you are getting that as you did not provide a complete MWE.  Also you were missing a `\` before `{` in the indicated line.

So, once you replace the definition of `\textsubscript`, this should do what you want.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand*{\textsubscript}[1]{$#1{}$}

\begin{document}
\begin{quote}
\noindent 
\textbf{110} in-parts{]} ~\textsubscript{^}~ || 
\textbf{112} long-smother'd{]} long 
\textsubscript{^}smothered ||  
\textbf{118} SD \emph{Exit Mons}.{]} 
\emph{placed as in Dilke; after l. 117} | 
\emph{with Pages}.{]} \emph{Boas subs}. | 
\emph{Manet Buss}.{]} \emph{after l. 119 }||  
\textbf{119} SD Rising.{]} (See Textual Note) ||  \textbf{122-126} Like \ldots soyl{]} \emph{stet} 
(\emph{See Textual Note}) ||  
\textbf{127} nourish any{]} norishany ||  
\textbf{130} for{]} \emph{stet} (\emph{See Textual Note}) | vertue,] ~; ||
\end{quote}

\begin{quote}
\noindent 
To be, or not to be, \{that is the q/Question\}/\{I there's the point,\} 
\ldots 
t/To \{d/Die/dye /,  --/ to sleepe, --/\}/\{die to sleepe,\} \{ \}/\{is that all? I all:\}% <--- missing a backslash here
\{ \}/ \{No,\} t/To sleepe ,/! {perchance}/\{ \} to d/Dreame ,/;/!  I/ay /, \{there's the rub,/;\}/\{mary there it goes,\}
\ldots
\{The faire Ophelia ,/?/:/! --/ Nimph/Nymph /,\}/\{Lady,\} in thy o/Orizons/orisons \{, be all my sinnes remembred\}/
\{Be all my sinnes remembred/remember'd.\}  /?
\end{quote}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked great!  I forgot about the MWE, I was so caught up in the formatting question.  Thank you for the definition of \textsubscript also.  I had been using a package for that but I must have deleted it on mistake.  This fixed it all right up.

Comment: @Wrigley242: You might also be missing some visible braces around `perchance`.